# How to get the full PHP documentation offline

Tags: php, documentation

I travel frequently and am often without an internet connection, so I've been looking for PHP offline documentation for Mac OSX.

I have used the [official offline PHP documentation](http://php.net/download-docs.php), but I am not able to find many functions with the official documentation, and the user comments are not included. For example: I was searching for PDO syntaxes with MySQL Support, but that is not included in the package.

I also tried [PHPfi](http://www.artissoftware.com/phpfi/history.html), but it seems to use the same data as the official offline PHP documentation.

How can I get the full PHP documentation offline?

Comment: Well, I use the CHM files and they have all the functions listed on the site as well. Are you sure you had the right files?

Comment: the problem is chm files are not supported by Mac, i need to buy a third party application for that.

Comment: Why don't you use the official chunked-html version? It also includes the `ref.pdo-mysql.html` for example.

Comment: @Mario yes it does have, but isn't it bit difficult to find functions this way ? i was looking for something which could help me find functions very easily.

Comment: Yes, agree. It would benefit from a built-in search function. Which begs the question, why didn't they bother to include a simple PHP search script and/or some rewriterules.

Comment: @Starx, why did you change the title of the page to unrelated topic? is something wrong with you?

Comment: @Ibrahim Azbar Armar, I am so sorry. I seemed to have completely lost it. Please forgive me. I will try to merely compensate my insolence with a vote. That's the least I could do. Again I am so sorry.

Comment: you can still always use `php --rc` and `--rf` to reflect on classes for their API. Doesnt have documentation to that though. But handy when you just want to look up if it's haystack or needle first.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I personally use the [.chm version](http://www.php.net/download-docs.php) of the manual - there are plenty of chm file readers for linux and OSX out there that can be used. It also offers integrated search, which is the main plus for it. The english chm download is also offered with the *user notes included*.

Also, php.net offers a the [php manual as man pages](http://bjori.blogspot.com/2010/01/unix-manual-pages-for-php-functions.html), installable via PEAR - it's awesome to integrate into i.e. emacs or vim.

```
$ pear channel-discover doc.php.net
$ pear install doc.php.net/pman
$ pman strpos
```

---

In the last years I have switched from chm viewers to [Zeal](https://zealdocs.org/), which provides docsets for several programming languages, including PHP.

You can also check http://devdocs.io/offline for offline, also available for Windows, Linux and Mac binaries.

Comment: You can also check http://devdocs.io/offline for offline, also available for Windows, Linux and Mac binaries.

Comment: If you are on Linux, xchmviewer will NOT display the manual properly. Only Kchmviewer works. :( GnoChm will not build with Ubuntu 20.04+ or Debian 10+ so you are stuck with kchmviewer... which kind of sucks for gtk folks :/
But hey, at least something works.  :D

Comment: devdocs no longer includes php ... so this no longer helps.